# My app's list is coming in alphabetical order separated by alphabet's(hear the main problem is alphabets are also showing on the screen)

Tags: lumia

hai i buy a new nokia lumia 520 yesterday i add only whats app & we chat app only but now the list (such as settings,angrybird, here maps,etc..,) all are changed & all are coming a new format separated by alphabets for example 
a
angry birds
application manager
b
book my show
big cinemas
.
.
.
s
settings

etc.., in this format i am getting but i am not interested to see like this in such methods so i want to bring my list as previous i had seen (after removing all apps also i am getting the list as alphabetical order) please try to solve my problem..,

Thank You in advance

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is expected on Windows Phone.

When the [App List](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-IE/how-to/wp8/basics/wheres-the-app-list) has less than 45 installed apps, you don't see the large letters before each group of apps. Your apps are still listed alphabetically, regardless.

The large letters you see are part of a Jump List. By tapping on a letter, it will bring up the alphabet (the jump list) - tapping on any letter will quickly bring you to that letter in your list of apps.

It's extremely handy when you have 200+ apps installed on your phone and you want to, say, start the People app (it saves having to scroll down a lot!)